# Unable to access API path through Loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, load-balancing

I have hosted websites and API in a single instance. Till then it was working fine, after enabling the LoadBalancer unable to access APIs.

For example, I'll get a response for http://www.example.com but the URL with a path starting with /api is not getting any response.

In Loadbalancer listener, I have enabled the rule for /api/*.

[image: My LoadBalancer rules]

Comment: Instead of /path/* you should use /api/*

Comment: @SubhashisPandey I have tried with /api/* as well, still not responding.

Comment: For testing purposes, can you remove all rules (only default left) and show the result? You should show the curl output, It's easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: @FranxiHidro, when I do request from postman or curl, returns 200, and when I am trying to access same from APP no response for the request.

Comment: @mohammedshajahan what do you mean from APP? you didn't mention it before.

Comment: Previously I was not able to access API's from anywhere. But now I'm able to access API's from postman and curl. When I Integrate API's into my app, no responses are coming.